Inconsistent solutions in two representations
Consider the following differential equations:
 diffeqns = {D[X[t], t] == (-I)*a*X[t] + b*Y[t], D[Y[t], t] == (-I)*a*Y[t] - b*X[t]}; 
FullSimplify[DSolve[diffeqns, {X[t], Y[t]}, t]]; 
sol1 = TrigToExp[%]; 
Collect[sol1, {C[1], C[2]}]
(*MatrixForm[{{X[t] -> ((1/2)*E^((-I)*a*t - I*b*t) + (1/2)*E^((-I)*a*t + I*b*t))*C[1] + 
      ((1/2)*I*E^((-I)*a*t - I*b*t) - (1/2)*I*E^((-I)*a*t + I*b*t))*C[2], 
    Y[t] -> ((-(1/2))*I*E^((-I)*a*t - I*b*t) + (1/2)*I*E^((-I)*a*t + I*b*t))*C[1] + 
      ((1/2)*E^((-I)*a*t - I*b*t) + (1/2)*E^((-I)*a*t + I*b*t))*C[2]}}]*)

Here a and b are complex constants independent of t.  The above solution reads:
\begin{equation}
X(t) = \frac{c_1+ic_2}{2}e^{-i(a+b)t} + \frac{c_1-ic_2}{2}e^{-i(a-b)t},\quad Y(t) = \frac{-ic_1+c_2}{2}e^{-i(a+b)t} + \frac{ic_1+c_2}{2}e^{-i(a-b)t}~~~(1)
\end{equation}
Fourier Transform $(F_w:=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dt e^{i w t} F(t))$ of $(1)$ is given by
\begin{equation}
X(w) = \frac{c_1+ic_2}{2} \delta(w-(a+b)) + \frac{c_1-ic_2}{2}\delta(w-(a-b)),\quad Y(w) = \frac{-ic_1+c_2}{2}\delta(w-(a+b)) + \frac{ic_1+c_2}{2}\delta(w-(a-b))~~~~~~~(2)
\end{equation}
Now consider the Fourier transform of diffeqns:
(-i)*w*Xw = (-i)*a*Xw + b*Yw; (-iw)*Yw = (-ia)*Yw - b*Xw

Surprisingly, one finds
Solve[{(-i)*w*Xw == (-i)*a*Xw + b*Yw, (-iw)*Yw == (-ia)*Yw - b*Xw}, {Xw, Yw}] (*=>Xw=Yw=0*)

i.e. $Xw=Yw=0$, which is different from $(2)$. How can one obtain the solution $(2)$, directly from the Fourier Transform of diffeqn given above?
